# How to run python scripts after CMD in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, cmd, docker-compose

I have a docker image that exposes 9000 port for server. After the server is running, I need to execute the 3 python scripts which depends on server so, they can only get executed after server.py is running however, after CMD command, the other code do not get executed and remains stuck. What are the possible suggestion to run 3 scripts in same container?

```
FROM python:3.7.3 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . . 

# CMD [ "python", "./server.py" ]   (The following 3 scripts depends on server.py for execution)

RUN python /app/script1.py
RUN python /app/script2.py
RUN python /app/script3.py

EXPOSE 9000

CMD [ "python", "./server.py" ]
```

Comment: friendly reminder to mark an answer as "accepted"! Never too late :)

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [Dockerfile referece](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile

The CMD instruction tells the container what its entry point is, and when running the container, that is what will be run.

If running `python ./server.py` is a blocking call (which I'm assuming it is, since it's called a server, and most likely responds to some kind of requests), then this won't be possible.

Instead, try restructuring your scripts so that they are run when the server is run, by doing everything you do in `script1.py`, `script2.py`, `script3.py` after the server has been started inside of `server.py`.

If instead this is about `script1.py`... sending requests to the server, I'd recommend not including those in the container. Instead, you can simply run those scripts, manually, from the terminal while the server container is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute those scripts from the command line using docker `exec` after the container has started. You'll just need to know what the container name is

```
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> python /app/script1.py
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> python /app/script2.py
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> python /app/script3.py
```

Or just make a bash script, say `my_script.sh` to run them all and just execute that

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> python /app/script1.py
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> python /app/script2.py
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> python /app/script3.py
```

And then

```
docker exec <CONTAINER NAME> ./my_script.sh
```